# new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext() creating new set of beans

Tags: java, spring

Does loading the application context in the following manner mean creating another context apart from the context created by a ContextLoader?

I require the application context to be loaded for a non-bean class.

```
private static ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "channel-integration-context.xml");
```

It seems that it creates another bean context according to my observation. If so what is a better workaround.

Please help.

Comment: To be specific, my concern is, I was under the impression that all classpath loaders such as above will refer the same "Spring Context" created at the point of container initializing, which is not the case it seems.!

Answer (score 1):

Unless some very special reason, usually there's no point of creating multiple `ApplicationContext`s.

You can create a singleton:

```
public class ApplicationContextWrapper {
    private static ApplicationContext INSTANCE = null;

    private ApplicationContextWrapper() {

    }

    public static ApplicationContext getIntance() {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            //note you can add more Spring XML configuration filenames in this array
            String[] contexts = new String[] {"channel-integration-context.xml"};
            INSTANCE = new ClassPathApplicationContext(contexts);
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

And you can use it with:

```
private static ApplicationContext applicationContext = ApplicationContextWrapper.getInstance();
```